JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: ~/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
In an effort to try to sync the jdk version of what Android Studio runs and what I run from the command line, I set my JAVA_HOME to the same jdk as my Android studio (which in this case is the JBR), in accordance with this doc
https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#jdk-config-in-studio
with the following command in my .zshrc file:
export JAVA_HOME="~/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home"
but when I try to run gradle as such ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest
it complains that it doesnt like the JBR:
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: ~/Applications/Android\     Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

my Java version  "1.8.0_411"
my gradle settings in AS:

